# How to change color of a Unicode text character in C++

Tags: c++, cmd, ascii

I am working on an ASCII 3D game engine and I don't know how to color a character using this current setup. The goal is to make each character a different color to add to the shading. I am using Windows 11's builtin command prompt.

Here's the code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int nScreenWidth = 120;
int nScreenHeight = 40;

float fPlayerX = 8.0f;
float fPlayerY = 7.0f;
float fPlayerView = 0.0f;


int nMapHeight = 16;
int nMapWidth = 16;

float fFOV = 3.14159 / 4.0;

float fDepth = 16.0f;

//COLORS LIST
//1: Blue
//2: Green
//3: Cyan
//4: Red
//5: Purple
//6: Yellow (Dark)
//7: Default white
//8: Gray/Grey
//9: Bright blue
//10: Brigth green
//11: Bright cyan
//12: Bright red
//13: Pink/Magenta
//14: Yellow
//15: Bright white

void Color(int color)
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), color);
}

int color;

int main()
{
    wchar_t* screen = new wchar_t[nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight];
    HANDLE hConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;

    std::wstring map;
    map += L"#########.......";
    map += L"#...............";
    map += L"#.......########";
    map += L"#..............#";
    map += L"#......##......#";
    map += L"#......##......#";
    map += L"#..............#";
    map += L"###............#";
    map += L"##.............#";
    map += L"#......####..###";
    map += L"#......#.......#";
    map += L"#......#.......#";
    map += L"#..............#";
    map += L"#......#########";
    map += L"#..............#";
    map += L"################";


    const HANDLE stdin_handle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

    while (true) {
        bool is_moving = false;

        if (GetAsyncKeyState((unsigned short)'A') & 0x8000) {
            fPlayerView -= (0.001f);
            is_moving = true;
        }

        if (GetAsyncKeyState((unsigned short)'D') & 0x8000) {
            fPlayerView += (0.001f);
            is_moving = true;
        }

        if (GetAsyncKeyState((unsigned short)'W') & 0x8000) {
            fPlayerX += sinf(fPlayerView) * 0.001f;
            fPlayerY += cosf(fPlayerView) * 0.001f;
            is_moving = true;

            if (map[(int)fPlayerY * nMapWidth + (int)fPlayerX] == '#') {
                fPlayerX -= sinf(fPlayerView) * 0.001f;
                fPlayerY -= cosf(fPlayerView) * 0.001f;
            }
        }

        if (GetAsyncKeyState((unsigned short)'S') & 0x8000) {
            fPlayerX -= sinf(fPlayerView) * 0.001f;
            fPlayerY -= cosf(fPlayerView) * 0.001f;
            is_moving = true;

            if (map[(int)fPlayerY * nMapWidth + (int)fPlayerX] == '#') {
                fPlayerX += sinf(fPlayerView) * 0.001f;
                fPlayerY += cosf(fPlayerView) * 0.001f;
            }
        }

        if (!is_moving) {
            WaitForSingleObject(stdin_handle, 100);
            continue;
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < nScreenWidth; x++) {
            float fRayAngle = (fPlayerView - fFOV / 2.0f) + ((float)x / (float)nScreenWidth) * fFOV;

            float fDistanceToWall = 0;
            bool bHitWall = false;
            bool bBounds = false;

            float fEyeX = sinf(fRayAngle);
            float fEyeY = cosf(fRayAngle);

            while (!bHitWall && fDistanceToWall < fDepth) {
                fDistanceToWall += 0.1f;

                int nTestX = (int)(fPlayerX + fEyeX * fDistanceToWall);
                int nTestY = (int)(fPlayerY + fEyeY * fDistanceToWall);

                if (nTestX < 0 || nTestX >= nMapWidth || nTestY < 0 || nTestY >= nMapHeight) {
                    bHitWall = true;
                    fDistanceToWall = fDepth;
                }
                else {
                    if (map[nTestY * nMapWidth + nTestX] == '#') {
                        bHitWall = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            int nCeiling = (float)(nScreenHeight / 2.0) - nScreenHeight / ((float)fDistanceToWall);
            int nFloor = nScreenHeight - nCeiling;

            short nShade = ' ';
            short fShade = ' ';

            if (fDistanceToWall <= fDepth / 4.0f) { nShade = 0x2588; }
            else if (fDistanceToWall < fDepth / 3.0f) { nShade = 0x2593; }
            else if (fDistanceToWall < fDepth / 2.0f) { nShade = 0x2592; }
            else if (fDistanceToWall < fDepth) { nShade = 0x2591; }
            else { nShade = ' '; }

            for (int y = 0; y < nScreenHeight; y++) {
                if (y < nCeiling) {
                    screen[y * nScreenWidth + x] = ' ';
                }
                else if (y > nCeiling && y <= nFloor) {
                    screen[y * nScreenWidth + x] = nShade;
                }
                else {
                    float b = 1.0f - (((float)y - nScreenHeight / 2.0f) / ((float)nScreenHeight / 2.0f));
                    if (b < 0.25) { fShade = 0x2588; color = 9;}
                    else if (b < 0.5) { fShade = 0x2593; color = 1;}
                    else if (b < 0.75) { fShade = 0x2592; color = 1;}
                    else if (b < 0.9){  fShade = 0x2591; color = 5;}
                    else { fShade = ' '; color = 0;}
                    Color(color);
                    screen[y * nScreenWidth + x] = fShade;
                }

            }

        }

        screen[nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight - 1] = '\0';
        WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, screen, nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight, { 0, 0 }, &dwBytesWritten);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to use system() to change the color and that resulted in a 0xc0000142 error. I also tried creating a function for it, so far that hasn't changed the color.

Comment: The concept of color doesn't exist in the C++ language per se, nor in ASCII.  It would depend on your operating system and possibly on your choice of terminal application, neither of which you have mentioned.  So please add details as well as the corresponding tags.

Comment: @NateEldredge Sorry about that, I added the Operating System and Terminal Application.

Comment: I don't see anywhere you've called the `Color` function.

Comment: @Retired Ninja Yeah I stopped calling it after I tried using it and it didn't change a thing.

Comment: Hard for us to tell you why it doesn't work when you're not using it.

Comment: @Retired Ninja Ok, I added it back exactly as I used it.

Comment: Just use escape sequences https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Another way to use colors is to use [ncurses](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/programming-color-ncurses) which is platform independent and will allow you more control over you output in other ways too

Comment: I recommend reading the Microsoft documentations for the [Console Funktions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions). But first look on left side and begin your research with reading [Windows Console and Terminal Ecosystem Roadmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/ecosystem-roadmap) and next __Definitions__, __Classic Console APIs versus Virtual Terminal Sequences__, all pages under __About Character Mode Applications__ and __About Consoles__ before you continue writing code for Windows console.

Comment: The usage of __Virtual Terminal Sequences__ makes writing code for colored text output in a Windows console much easier than using the classic console API functions, but limits the usage of the console program to some of the newest Windows 10 versions and Windows 11 and excludes older versions of Windows 10 and all older Windows versions. It is therefore really useful to have read all the general Windows console documentation pages to get the necessary knowledge making the right coding design concept decisions before starting the code development.

Comment: There is the documentation for [SetConsoleTextAttribute function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletextattribute) with an __Important__ paragraph at top which should be considered seriously. You try to use that function, but obviously not right. The second function parameter is of type `WORD` (underlying type is `unsigned short` ... 16-bit unsigned integer value) and not of type `int`. It is never wrong using the correct type for variables of which values are passed to a Windows library function. Turn on all compiler warnings to get informed about type mismatches.

Comment: Sure, `int` is for 32-bit and 64-bit compilation larger than `unsigned short` and the C++ compiler can do an implicit type conversion already during the compilation of the source code, but it is nevertheless better to use the correct type for variables of which values are passed to functions of Windows standard libraries like `SetConsoleTextAttribute`.